# Formally can money be in a plural form (monies) or not?

Tags: plural-forms, singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I have studied that money is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), but now I saw that money can be in plural form as well. So I am confused. when we say on something that it's uncountable, then should it not be in one form only? (without singular/ plural - and like water, milk etc.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. For example, "monies owed" means "sums owed" [to various people].

Comment: I'd have expected the "more regular" form ***moneys*** to be well out in front, particularly given [*Garner’s Modern American Usage and the AP Stylebook suggest that **moneys** is the better spelling*.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/money-monies-or-moneys) But apparently [*any **monies** owed*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=any+moneys+owed%2Cany+monies+owed&year_start=1940&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cany%20moneys%20owed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cany%20monies%20owed%3B%2Cc0) has suddenly taken over in the last couple of decades.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So, to clarify, you'd have expected ***moneys*** to be well out in front... _in America_. Right? Otherwise I don't see the relevance of an "American Usage" guide.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I'm not a lawyer, but I've seen lots of legal texts over the years, and ***monies*** strikes me as a "quaint" spelling. Since I'm a Brit, I wouldn't often see *American* usages (I only cited Garners because that's what I found when I googled **monies vs moneys**), but checking NGram BrE/AmE corpuses for [money/monies owed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monies+owed%2Cmoneys+owed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmonies%20owed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoneys%20owed%3B%2Cc0) they look much the same to me.

Comment: I note that with ***a moneyed man/family/etc.***, that spelling is consistently more common than ***monied***. As I suggested below, perhaps the latter has some special appeal to new entrants in the legal profession.

Answer (score 13):

In ordinary usage, nouns like "milk" and "water" are uncountable.   There are times, however, when such words do have a countable sense.   For example, cows produce a different milk than goats.   If I want to compare those two milks, then I'm using the word "milk" in a countable sense and phrases like "a different milk" and "those two milks" are natural and sensible.

In financial contexts, it is natural and sensible to talk about different countable monies.   The USD and the Euro are two different monies.   Taxable income and tax-free income are two different monies.

Strictly speaking, it isn't necessary to force a countable sense onto an uncountable noun.   It is just as natural and sensible to talk about "two types of milk" or "two kinds of money", which allows "milk" and "money" to retain their ordinary, uncountable meanings.   Your cited definition includes the phrase "as used in financial contexts".   A better phrasing might be "as used in financial [jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon)".

Comment: I've never heard of the US dollar and the euro being described as "monies", but as *currencies*. [*Sterling is reaping its best gains against higher-yielding commodity **currencies** like the South African Rand and Aussie Dollar at present.*](https://www.poundsterlinglive.com/gbp-live-today/5754-gbp-firms-vs-eur-and-usd-merkel-comments) I'm not doubting that the plural form is ever used, but I would say it's extremely rare, and probably restricted to very specific instances, see @Hank's answer .

Comment: "I've never heard of the US dollar and the euro being described as "monies", but as currencies."  They're called "monies", when they are, faute de mieux -- what terms could be used if not those?  A writer would have to resort to circumlocution.

Comment: I'd say a better example is when you have two or more *types* of debt or income; these can be referred to as "monies owing" and "monies owed".

Comment: another use of monies is when you talk about the "monies market" where different types of money are exchanged

Comment: @MMacD: as Mari-Lou says, dollars and Euros are currencies, not monies.

Comment: @TopherBrink No, they should be called the currency markets.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff:  Then what are the names of the corresponding monies?

Comment: "Monies" is the wrong word. It's not applicable here.

Comment: monies market =/= currencies market, the monies market is "the trade in short-term loans between banks and other financial institutions"

Comment: "Monies" is the wrong word. It's not applicable here."  Then what word IS applicable?  That's my point:  if we want to talk about monies, we must have a word to use, and the only word I know is "monies".  Do you know a better one?

Answer (score 11):

Although `Money` is a mass noun, and therefore doesn't NEED a plural form, *Garner* and *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* explain that `Monies` is usually used by legal or finance writers to talk about “individual sums” or “discrete sums” of money. That being said, `Monies`, and even `Moneys`, can technically be used to refer to the plural form of `Money`, despite most people disliking it.

Although it makes it more confusing, all rules come with rare exceptions.

Comment: Re "or even **moneys**" - per my comment above, apparently Garner's actually *recommend* that form. But presumably a new generation of legal types like the somewhat archiac / "authoritative" overtones of the quaint oddball spelling **monies**.

Comment: Interestingly, Fowler has nothing to say on the subject at all.